# Compare query result to array PHP

Tags: php, sql, arrays, sorting

I have an array $columns which contains the chosen values from the user. The user values is supposed to be saved in a database table so that the next time, the user wont be given points for the values that he or she chose the last time. Messy? A bit of code plz? ok:

```
$columns= isset($_POST['column']) ? $_POST['column'] : array();
print_r($columns);
```

So all columns that is chosen gets the value 1, and the other ones have value 0. This gives me:

```
Array ( [0] => 1 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [4] => 1 [7] => 1 )
```

I have a database table with 8 different columns namned column1,column2,columnN....
I want to compare the database table to my array. To know which column to update. Now im thinking:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {
    if($row['column'.$checks]!=1){
        //update table with values
     }
    }
```

Should I compare my array to $row? or intersection? how can I get the values needed from my array?

Comment: **[Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code.](http://bit.ly/phpmsql)** They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the **[red box](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)**? You can use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) instead - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://www.brightmeup.info/article.php?a_id=2).

Comment: Thank you! will look in to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not merge all those tables into one.

```
id  |  column_id  |  check
```

Which will make updating values a lot easier

```
foreach ($columns as $column_id => $value) {
   // UPDATE `table` SET check = {$value} WHERE column_id = {$column_id};
}
```

Comment: but wont the table look like (ID->1 column_id->1,2,3,6,7 check->1) or :)?

Comment: No! because you are looping over all column id's and updating one at a time!